# Combos dependientes php postgres

Tags: php, html

amigos, estoy trabajando con html, php y postgres. Tengo dos tablas en mi base

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y con el siguiente código pretendo llenar dos combos, que en el primero muestre los grupos de animales (tabla GRUPO) y en función del grupo que se elija, se cargue el segundo combo los animales correspondientes de esa grupo (tabla ANIMALES).

```
    <?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "animales";
$user = "postgres";
$pw = "admin";
$port = "5432";
$packedString = "host=" . $host . " dbname=" . $dbname . " user=" . $user . " password=" . $pw . " port=" . $port;
$db = pg_connect("$packedString")or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
?>
//***** combos_combinados.php *****//
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      // Función que rellena el segundo combo según el valor seleccionado en el primero.
      // Se le pasa como parámetro el nombre del formulario desde el cuál se llama a la función
      function rellenaCombo(formulario)
      {
        with (document.forms[formulario])  // Establecemos por defecto el nombre formulario pasado para toda la función.
        {
          var cat = id_grupo[id_grupo.selectedIndex].value; // Valor seleccionado en el primer combo.
          var n = id_animal.length;  // Numero de líneas del segundo combo.

          id_animal.disabled = false;  // Activamos el segundo combo.

          for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            id_animal.remove(id_animal.options[i]); // Eliminamos todas las líneas del segundo combo.

          id_animal[0] = new Option("Seleccione un animal", 'null'); // Creamos la primera línea del segundo combo.

          if (cat != 'null')  // Si el valor del primer combo es distinto de 'null'.
          {
   <?php
    // Para cada grupo, construimos el segundo combo con los animales del mismo.
    $cons_cat = @pg_exec($db, "SELECT * FROM grupo;");

    for ($l = 0; $l < pg_numrows($cons_cat); ++$l)
    {
     $cen = @pg_fetch_object($cons_cat, $l);
   ?>
            if (cat == '<?php echo $cat->id_grupo;?>')
            {
    <?php
          // Construimos los valores del segundo combo con los animales de grupo
      $cons_rez = @pg_exec($db, "SELECT * FROM animal WHERE id_grupo = ".$cat->id_grupo." ORDER BY nombre_animal;");

      for ($m = 0; $m < pg_numrows($cons_rez); ++$m)
      {
       $rez = @pg_fetch_object($cons_rez, $m);
    ?>
              id_animal[id_animal.length] = new Option("<?php echo $rez->nombre_animal;?>", '<?php echo $rez->id_grupo;?>');
    <?php
      }
    ?>
            }
   <?php
    }
   ?>
            Id_animal.focus();  // Enviamos el foco al segundo combo.
          }
          else  // El valor del primer combo es 'null'.
          {
            Id_animal.disabled = true;  // Desactivamos el segundo combo (que estará vacío).
            id_grupo.focus();  // Enviamos el foco al primer combo.
          }

          id_animal.selectedIndex = 0;  // Seleccionamos el primer valor del segundo combo ('null').
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <form name="datos" method="post" action="...">

            <select name="id_grupo" onChange="rellenaCombo('datos');">
              <option value="null" selected>Seleccione un grupo de animales
<?php
// CODIGO PHP
 // Contruimos el primer combo con los valores de la tabla 'grupo'.
 $cons_cat = @pg_exec($db, "SELECT * FROM grupo;");

 for ($k = 0; $k < pg_numrows($cons_cat); ++$k)
 {
  $cat = @pg_fetch_object($cons_cat, $k);
  echo "              <option value=\"".$cat->id_grupo."\">".$cat->grupo."\n";
 }
?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="id_animal" disabled>
            <option value="null">Seleccione un animal
          </select>
        </td>
        </form>

      </tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Pero, sólo me carga el primer combo y hasta allí se queda***

la consola me lanza estos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes revisar esta publicación, explica a detalle lo que necesitas, el motor de BD es distinta pero la lógica te puede servir.  https://codigosdeprogramacion.com/2017/01/15/combobox-select-dinamicos-en-php-ajax-y-mysql/

Comment: Para mi ese es otro problema, ya que toda la información que encuentro respecto a combos dependientes es con Mysql, pero no sé como adaptar ese código a Postgres @SilvestreSilva